# Stop return from javascript function until SetTimeout executes

Tags: javascript

I am using a fabric.js to draw a binary tree/graph, I want to introduce a delay so that the sequence of drawing is visible. I used setTimeout method in my code but problem is all the nodes are getting delayed and drawn at the same time which I don't want. I want one node,then little delay then another node. Kindly help me.

Code:

```
delaytime=5000;

function add(x){
   console.log(x);
   canvas.add(x);
}



function addRoot(value){

    var value=String(value);
    var x=new fabric.Circle({ radius: radius,left:width/2,fill:'red',top:radius,originX: 'center', originY: 'center',fill:'red'});
    var text= new fabric.Text(value, {fontSize: 10, originX: 'center', originY: 'center',left:width/2,top:radius});

    setTimeout(function(){ add(x);},delaytime);
  setTimeout(function(){ add(text);},delaytime);



    return x;
}
```

In the code above the two setTimeout calls are getting executed at the same time but I want the program waits until it returns from first setTimeout call even if it is 5 seconds and then execute the next statement. Please give hints.

Async/await is also not working. Only first call getting drawn which is addRoot

Test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test for fabric</title>

</head>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800" style="border:1px solid #000000">


</canvas>
<script src="fabric.js"></script>
    <script src="testfunctions.js">

    </script>
<script src="./testfunctions.js"></script>
<script>

    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    var a10=addRoot(10);
    var a20=addNode(a10,20,225);
    var a40=addNode(a10,40,315);
    var a30=addNode(a20,30,270);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Code with async:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var height = parseInt(document.getElementById('canvas').getAttribute('height'));
var width = parseInt(document.getElementById('canvas').getAttribute('width'));
var distance = 200;
var radius = 20;
var linelimit = 180;
var delaytime = 1000;

 async function delay (time) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, time)
  })
}


async function addRoot (value) {
    var value = String(value);
    var x = new fabric.Circle({ radius: radius, left: width / 2, fill: 'red', top: radius, originX: 'center', originY: 'center', fill: 'red'});
    var text = new fabric.Text(value, {fontSize: 10, originX: 'center', originY: 'center', left: width / 2, top: radius});
    await delay(1000);
    canvas.add(x);
    canvas.add(text);
    return x
}

function addline (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  console.log("In addline");
  var line = new fabric.Line([x1, y1, x2, y2], {stroke: 'black', originX: 'center', originY: 'center'});
  canvas.add(line)
}


 async function  addNode (node1, node2, angle) {
  var intialx = parseInt(node1.left);

  var initialy = parseInt(node1.top);

   console.log("addNode");

  if (angle > 0 && angle <= 90) {
    var pointx = Math.abs(Math.abs(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance) + intialx);
    var pointy = Math.abs(Math.abs(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance) - initialy);

    var initiallinex = Math.abs(Math.abs(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * radius) + intialx);
    var initialliney = Math.abs(Math.abs(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * radius) - initialy);
    var finallinex = Math.abs(Math.abs(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * linelimit) + intialx);
    var finalliney = Math.abs(Math.abs(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * linelimit) - initialy)
  }
  if (angle > 90 && angle <= 180) {
    var pointx = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance + intialx);
    var pointy = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance - initialy);

    var initiallinex = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * radius + intialx);
    var initialliney = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * radius - initialy);
    var finallinex = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * linelimit + intialx);
    var finalliney = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * linelimit - initialy)
  }
  if (angle > 180 && angle <= 270) {
    if (angle == 270) {
      var pointx = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance + intialx);
      var pointy = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance - initialy);
      var initiallinex = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * radius + intialx);
      var initialliney = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * radius - initialy);
      var finallinex = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * linelimit + intialx);
      var finalliney = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * linelimit - initialy)
    } else {
      var pointx = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance + intialx);
      var pointy = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance - initialy);
      var initiallinex = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * radius + intialx);
      var initialliney = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * radius - initialy);
      var finallinex = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * linelimit + intialx);
      var finalliney = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * linelimit - initialy)
    }
  } else {
    var pointx = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance + intialx);
    var pointy = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance - initialy);
    var initiallinex = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * radius + intialx);
    var initialliney = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * radius - initialy);
    var finallinex = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * linelimit + intialx);
    var finalliney = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * linelimit - initialy)
  }

  var x = new fabric.Circle({ radius: radius, originX: 'center', originY: 'center', fill: 'red', left: pointx, top: pointy});
  var value1 = String(node2);
  var text = new fabric.Text(value1, {fontSize: 10, originX: 'center', originY: 'center', left: pointx, top: pointy});
  await delay(1000);
  canvas.add(x);
  canvas.add(text);
  await delay(1000);
  console.log("Executed");
  addline(initiallinex, initialliney, finallinex, finalliney);
  return x;
}
```

Comment: One simple fix is multiply `delaytime` x 2 in second timer. Problem is not specific enough if this needs to be done multiple times

Comment: move the setTimeout to where you want it to be called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES2017 [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) / [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

```js
function delay (time) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, time)
  })
}

let delaytime = 1000

async function addRoot (value) {
  console.log('do stuff')
  // var value=String(value);
  // var x=new fabric.Circle({ radius: radius,left:width/2,fill:'red',top:radius,originX: 'center', originY: 'center',fill:'red'});
  // var text= new fabric.Text(value, {fontSize: 10, originX: 'center', originY: 'center',left:width/2,top:radius});
  await delay(delaytime)
  console.log('add x')
  // add(x);
  await delay(delaytime)
  console.log('add text')
  // add(text);
  return { value: value }
  // return x;
}

// usage
addRoot('some value').then(function (returnedValue) {
  console.log(returnedValue)
})
```

Notice the delay in the timestamps next to each `console.log()` output in the demo.

### Update

In order to properly use this code with minimal change to yours, change the following snippet:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var a10=addRoot(10);
var a20=addNode(a10,20,225);
var a40=addNode(a10,40,315);
var a30=addNode(a20,30,270);
```

to this:

```
// to support await operator
(async function () {
  // do not declare another canvas, you've already done so in other block
  var a10 = await addRoot(10)
  var a20 = await addNode(a10, 20, 225)
  var a40 = await addNode(a10, 40, 315)
  var a30 = await addNode(a20, 30, 270)
})()
```

Comment: I want to use function like addRoot() only

Comment: @OmkarKeluskar I've placed `console.log()`s where you should put your application logic. Considering that your example code is incomplete, I would not be able to produce a working demo if I didn't use `console.log()`s.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, i am getting some error when copying the function delay , the errors are:  a) expression expected at =>,{ expected at setTimeout function closing braces and expecting a new line  or semicolon in the end. I am using WebStorm IDE any tips?

Comment: @OmkarKeluskar I am not familiar with WebStorm IDE, but I suspect it does not support arrow functions, so, I'll update my answer to remove them.

Comment: @OmkarKeluskar upon googling [WebStorm ES2017 support](https://www.google.com/search?q=WebStorm+ES2017), a link on the first page of results suggests [changing your JavaScript language version](https://medium.com/@brandonaaskov/enabling-es6-syntax-support-in-webstorm-48e22956ecfd).

Comment: I did that and no results sadly, any other IDE suggestion?

Comment: @OmkarKeluskar from what I can see, WebStorm offers a lot of advanced functionality that most free text editors don't, but if you can live without those advanced features, basically any text editor will do. I personally use Sublime Text for most of my editing purposes, and just run [`standard`](https://standardjs.com/) to do basic error checking and code formatting. You should really learn how to debug your code properly though, so that you don't have to rely on others to produce _exactly_ the code you need, when they've already given you an idea of how to do something.

Comment: Hi @Patrick , I tried to run this code but it is not working as expected, only one node is getting drawn, I have updated the code.

Comment: @OmkarKeluskar That's because you're not calling it properly. Please see my updated usage. I really recommend you read the tutorial links I put in my answer on `async` and `await`, because it's clear that you don't understand how to invoke `async` functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve what you want to do

(1) add additional `delaytime` at the last `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function() {

  add(x);
}, delaytime);

setTimeout(function() {

  add(text);
}, delaytime * 2);
```

(2) Place the last `setTimeout` inside the first `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function() {

  add(x);
  setTimeout(function() {

    add(text);
  }, delaytime);
}, delaytime);
```

Comment: Basically there are other functions also which are used to draw so I dont think this approach would work

Comment: Problem with first approach is that i have several calls like:                               a)Addroot() and then addNode() so I want addroot to draw a root node with delay and then program should move to addNode() function which is not happening right now